# Can't create bootable USB with WoeUSB

Tags: ubuntu, usb, windows, bootable, fat32

When I try to create a Windows 10 bootable USB on my Linux Ubuntu 18.04 with WoeUSB it gives me this error:

```
Installation failed!
Exit code: 256
Log:
WoeUSB v@@WOEUSB_VERSION@@
==============================
Mounting source filesystem...
Error: File "/media/woeusb_source_1548324574_1839/sources/install.wim" 
in source image has exceed the FAT32 Filesystem 4GiB Single File Size 
Limitation and cannot be installed.  You must specify a different -- 
target-filesystem.
Refer: https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB/wiki/Limitations#fat32- 
filesystem-4gib-single-file-size-limitation for more info.
Unmounting and removing "/media/woeusb_source_1548324574_1839"...
You may now safely detach the target device
```

My USB has 8GB of storage.

Comment: Try to run `woeusb` in text mode (in a terminal window) and create an NTFS file system according to my answer at the following link: [WoeUSB Error Code 256 with NTFS formatted USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097560/woeusb-error-code-256-with-ntfs-formatted-usb/1098185#1098185)

Answer (score 1):

As per [a Microsoft forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/what-is-the-maximum-file-size-fat-fat32-ntfs-file/1663db6b-490e-4021-9e36-f7a6976ac0c0) and the [explanation from WoeUSB](https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB/wiki/Limitations#fat32-filesystem-4gib-single-file-size-limitation) shown above, the maximum size of a single file on a FAT32 device is 4 GiB. That file system [uses a 32-bit field to store the file size in bytes](https://superuser.com/questions/440509/getting-around-the-fat32-4gb-file-size-limit), and 2^32 bytes = 4 GiB (actually, the real limit is 4 GiB minus one byte, or 4 294 967 295 bytes, because you can have files of zero length). {Thanks to a [SuperUser poster *a CVn*](https://superuser.com/users/53590/a-cvn) for the explanation why).

Your file 'install.wim' is larger than 4 GiB, so it can't be written to a FAT32 device.  Sadly, Microsoft keeps putting more and more into the Windows installer, and it has grown larger than FAT32 will allow.

SOLUTION: Format the USB using NTFS which permits files >4 GiB *before* you create the LiveUSB. Right-click on the USB once inserted, and choose Format, then [choose NTFS in the Type field](https://i0.wp.com/itsfoss.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/create-bootable-windows-usb-in-linux-3.jpeg?w=831&ssl=1).

When the USB drive is formatted, then open WoeUSB and it will allow you to create a LiveUSB [with the huge Windows .WIM file](https://i1.wp.com/itsfoss.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/create-bootable-windows-usb-in-linux-4.jpeg?w=648&ssl=1).